# How to use SQLite in executable jar file?

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite, executable

I make a Java project with SQLite database I want to make my project to Java executable file. When I run the project in Eclipse, everything is fine but when I export the project and run that, the database doesn't work.

- `talarferdosi.db` is my database file and that is under the `src` folder.
- Version of the SQLite.jar is 3.6.14.1.
- `String sql ="SELECT price FROM fastfood WHERE name='pizza'";`

If I add the dependency of the SQLite to `pom.xml` it's gonna work or not?

This is my connection code to SQLite.

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:talarferdosi.db");
    st=con.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: 1) Change `ex.getMessage();` (which does **nothing** useful) to `ex.printStackTrace();` and run the Jar from the command line, then copy/paste the output as an [edit] to the question (also using code formatting). 2) Also note that it won't be possible to update a DB in a Jar.

Comment: It seems to be a resource on the class path; for a read-only database. Add the dependency to the pom.xml. Also check the jar (zip format). /src/main/resources/talarferdosi.db should be in the jar as /talarferdosi.dbf. Maybe you need to copy the resource to the file system: `Files.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/talarferdosi.db"), Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "talarferdosi.dbf"));` and use that location for the connection.